# Is there a free program allowing to create very simple sound/audio loops?

Tags: audio, audio-editing

I'd like to create a simple, extremely low frequency sound that I can play indefinitely in my web app.

I suppose the studio emulation Reason is able to do this, but obviously it's not free. I'm looking for a free alternative, a simple program to generate simple loop sounds.

Comment: Have you explored Audacity?

Comment: Can you generate sounds from scratch with Audacity? (I thought it was only to do editing)

Comment: I misread or incompletely read your question. I don't think Audacity is a generator type of program. Shucks.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a compilation of [six purportedly free programs](https://listoffreeware.com/free-software-synthesizer-software-windows/) for creating sounds for looping or any other purpose. I say "purportedly" because at least one of them is limited in the free version and the review suggests that it's buggy.

As you did not reference an operating system, I limited this response to Windows based programs.

[LMMS](https://lmms.io/)

[Magic Music Maker](http://www.magix.com/us/music-maker/)

[FL Studio](https://www.image-line.com/downloads/flstudiodownload.html)

[Hydrogen](http://www.hydrogen-music.org/hcms/node/21)

[Music Keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9WZDNCRDFJH2)

All above links taken from the compilation link at the top of this post.